# Negative istekhara

Tags: nikah, dua, istikharah

A.O.A
I met a guy before 7 months and i really like him he also likes me so we want to marry each other. So for that purpose we asked a moulvi to do istekhara for us n he told us that your istakara came negative. But we want to do nikkah and we are very serious for each other plz trll me is there anyway so that Allah will also agree with our marriage and the result will be positive. And what if i ignore the negative sign of istekhara and pray again of our marriage in front of Allah? Plz help me i m really confused and tensed and i dont want to leave him and we are not doing anything wrong we just want to do nikkah and to spend life with eachother.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Why didn't you both do istikhara? Leaving a third person do istikhara is a rather discussed topic among scholars. Please click on the tag istikhara you may find posts answering your inquiry.

Answer (score -1):

You can do istikhara as many times you want.

Also you can go opposite to results of istikhara, it is not like going against Allah, you both can get married.

Also remember dua is a very powerful gift from Allah which can change things.

Lastly just an advise, while going for marriage two factors are very important; other person's religious attachments. More a person is God fearing the better. And second is Ikhlaq, compassion is the key to happy marriage life.